# Can't add user to gitolite repository

Tags: git, ssh-keys, openssh, gitolite

I use gitolite script to create projects (repos) and add users.
I have already 3 users - 2 are developers, 1 is for jenkins.

They have access via ssh (simply generated RSA keys for each one and added them to gitolite keydir, and added users to gitolite.conf). Everthing is ok in this part - all for 3 users have access to repositories.

Then I tryied to add new developer - he generated keys, I made all required iterations to add him to project (edited gitolite.conf, added .pub key to keydir).
But... access is denied for him. I tryied to generate new key pair and added new user by myself from my computer (I replaced my working(!) keys by new and tryied to access project) - no access.

When I execute `ssh -vvvv git@myserver.com` ssh-client send the pub key to server but I have this lines in the end of stack trace:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: ~/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: ~/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: ~/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: ~/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@myserver.com's password:
```

When I use my old (working) key pair `ssh -vvvv git@myserver.com` return access granted.

Then, I checked `/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server - everything is ok - keys are on right  place.
Checked keydir folder on server - keys are on right place.

Then I tryied to remove and than add jenkins user and keys from/to project (I used old keys) - ok, access granted.
Then I generated new key pair for jenkins user on server, removed user from project and keys from keydir, and than added new keys to gitolite keydir and new jenkins user to project (gitolite.conf) - no access.

Anyone have any ideas?

P.S. all remove/add user/keys actions were made by gitolite-admin

Comment: I have the answer for my problem! The /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys file contains all users but etc/ssh/git/authorized_keys doesn not. So adding authorized_keys file from git user .ssh folder to servers ssh git folder resolved my problem

Comment: think that gitolite shoud update etc/ssh/authorized_keys file automatically

Comment: Please answer your own question, and accept the answer later to close the issue. And report the problem upstream!